# Get holding ObservableCollection of Instance by NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs or sender

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I have a List of House-Objects. These inherit ObservableCollections of Persons

```
public class House{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Residents = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    ...
}
```

In any class i added the Residents-Handler

```
List<House> Village = new List<House>(); 
foreach (House h in Village) {
    h.Residents.CollectionChanged += OnResidents_Changed;
}
```

Handling:

```
private void OnResidents_Changed(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.NewItems!= null) {
        foreach(Person p in e.NewItems){
            //In which house did he go?
            e.GetSourceCollection() //<- how to solve
        }
    }
}
```

The person should also can be in more than one house at the same time. I have no possibility to change the persons attributes.

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sender` argument holds the ObservableCollection instance:

```
private void OnResidents_Changed(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var collection = (ObservableCollection<Person>)sender;

    ...
}
```

---

As a note, you should declare the collection as a (readonly) property instead of a field, to make it accessible to WPF data binding:

```
public class House
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Residents { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    ...
}
```

Comment: I thought this too, but the sender is of type `Person`; not of type `ObservableCollection<Person>`, don't know why!? But it's the same behavior in every ObservableCollection.

[see Microsoft API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) But this isn't very precise :/

Comment: No, the sender is the ObservableCollection. If it's not, then we're not talking about the code in your question.

Comment: Ohh you were right! Sorry, was my fault. In my case, i castet the collection to type House not to type Person :/ Thank you for your answer!! Didn't see it.
The question now appears quite trivial.